# Evaluate the inward flux of the vector field $F=<y,-x,z>$ over the surface $S$ of the solid bounded by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=3$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the inward flux of the vector field $F=<y,-x,z>$ over the surface $S$ of the solid bounded by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=3$.

this is basically an inverted cone (right?)

So by changing to polar coordinates: $0\leq r\leq3$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

$$-\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3-y\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + x\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\space \space \times rdrd\theta$$
Simplified to
$$-\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3r^2drd\theta $$
Did i make any mistakes here? because i solved this to be $-18\pi$ but the answer given is $-9\pi$

I'm thinking maybe the range for $\theta$ is wrong but then it can't be because the conditions require full circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solid body can be described in cylindrical coordinates as

$$\Omega  = \left\{ {\left( {r,\theta ,z} \right)|0 \le r \le 3,0 \le \theta  \le 2\pi ,r \le z \le 3} \right\}$$

In fact, the surface surrounding your body, $\partial \Omega $, consist of **two** other surfaces

$$\begin{array}{l}
\partial \Omega  = {S_1} \cup {S_2}\\
{S_1} = \left\{ {\left( {r,\theta ,z} \right)|0 \le r \le 3,0 \le \theta  \le 2\pi ,z = 3} \right\}\\
{S_2} = \left\{ {\left( {r,\theta ,z} \right)|0 \le r \le 3,0 \le \theta  \le 2\pi ,z = r} \right\}
\end{array}$$

You have just computed the flux toward $S_1$, i.e., the plane $z=3$! :)

Comment: oh..damn! i did notice that. but how do i computer the $S_2$ one then? using spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Danxe: I think cylindrical will do the job! Are you asked to compute the flux directly? If **NOT** you can just use the divergence theorem and compute one volume integral instead of two surface integrals! :)

Comment: i have not learnt the divergence theorem yet. yeah in this topic we focused on integral over surfaces and i have so much trouble identifying the surfaces

Comment: You will learn after some practicing! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to practice on definition of surface integrals, I would suggest you not to use any "ready formulas" as Stokes' theorem, for example, but try first to gain basic understanding for the underlying geometry. A solution could look like the following:

1. Split the vector field into two
   $$
   F=\underbrace{(y,-x,0)}_{F_1}+\underbrace{(0,0,z)}_{F_2}.
   $$
   Notice that the first one $F_1$ is a planar vector field that belongs to the tangent space for both surfaces, hence, its flux is zero, and we have to calculate only the flux of the second one (easier!).
2. On the top surface $S_1$ (the disc in the plane $z=3$) we have $F_2=(0,0,3)$, which is (anti)parallel to the surface inward normal $n_1=(0,0,-1)$, and the scalar product of those vectors is $-3$. So the surface integral becomes
   $$
   \iint_{S_1} F_2\cdot n_1\,dA=-3\iint_{S_1}\,dA=-3\cdot\text{the disc area}=-3\cdot \pi 3^2=-27\pi.
   $$
3. On the side surface $S_2$ it is a bit trickier. The inward normal $n_2$ has the same angle $\pi/4$ with the vector field, so the scalar product is $F_2\cdot n_2=|F_2||n_2|\cos\pi/4=z/\sqrt{2}$, and the integral becomes
   $$
   \iint_{S_2}F_2\cdot n_2\,dA=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\iint_{S_2}z\,dA.
   $$
   The surface area element $dA$ corresponds to the area of the narrow band around the cone between levels $z$ and $z+dz$ and [can be approximated](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html) as $2\pi z\cdot \sqrt2 dz$ that gives
   $$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\iint_{S_2}z\,dA=2\pi\int_0^3z^2\,dz=18\pi.
   $$
4. Adding together we get $-27\pi+18\pi=-9\pi$.

P.S. Using the [Gauss-Ostrogradsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), the problem is actually trivial, since the divergence of $F$ is $1$, so the space integral is simply the volume of the cone $\frac13\cdot\pi3^2\cdot 3=9\pi$. (Note the sign - the theorem is for the outward normal.)